# Error running lambda function locally: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I am trying to run an AWS Lambda function locally, but when I run the code I get the following error:

```
String indices must be integers
```

This is the function that is causing the error:

```py
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    logger.debug('Received event: {}'.format(event))
    print(event['Item']) 
    operations = {
        'DELETE': lambda dynamo, x: dynamo.delete_item(**x),
        'POST': lambda dynamo, x: dynamo.put_item(**x),
        'PUT': lambda dynamo, x: dynamo.update_item(**x),
        'GET': lambda dynamo, x: dynamo.get_item(**x),
        'GET_ALL': lambda dynamo, x: dynamo.scan(**x),
        'BATCH_WRITE': lambda dynamo, x: dynamo.batch_write_item(**x),
    }
    for record in event['Item']:
        print(record['body'])
        payload = loads(record['body'], parse_float=str)
        operation = record['messageAttributes']['Method']['stringValue']
        if operation in operations:
            try:
                operations[operation](dynamo_client, payload)
                logger.info('{} method successful'.format(operation))
                logger.debug('Event payload: {}'.format(payload))
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error(e)
                # return -1
        else:
            logger.error('Unsupported method \'{}\''.format(operation))
            # return -1
    return 0
```

I am passing this JSON object to invoke the function locally:

```json
{ 
    "TableName":"DemoTable",
    "Item":
            {"make":{"S":"Ford"},
             "type":{"S":"Sedan"},
             "fuelType":{"S":"gas"},
             "miles":{"S":"50000"},
             "model":{"S":"Fiesta"},
             "year":{"S":"2018"}}
}
```

Below error from console

[DEBUG] 2022-07-03T15:09:24.716Z         Received event: {'TableName': 'DemoTable', 'Item': {'make': {'S': 'Ford'}, 'type': {'S': 'Sedan'}, 'fuelType': {'S': 'gas'}, 'miles': {'S': '50000'}, 'model': {'S': 'Fiesta'}, 'year': {'S': '2018'}}}
{'make': {'S': 'Ford'}, 'type': {'S': 'Sedan'}, 'fuelType': {'S': 'gas'}, 'miles': {'S': '50000'}, 'model': {'S': 'Fiesta'}, 'year': {'S': '2018'}}
payload = loads(record['body'], parse_float=str)r
END
{"errorMessage": "string indices must be integers", "errorType": "TypeError",  "stackTrace": ["  File "/var/task/app.py", line 29, in lambda_handler\n    payload = loads(record['body'], parse_float=str)\n"]}

Comment: i am getting below error 
{"errorMessage": "string indices must be integers", "errorType": "TypeError

Comment: Hi and welcome.
You should check your question structure , give it a proper title and give a little more context, for example what line does return that error message? This seems to be an error that is not with Lambda but with your inner code itself, is hard to tell with such a small context.

Comment: Hi @Sam, could you please include more details such as the line that is causing the error?

Comment: @NicholasObert i have added the error from console where i am getting error on line no 29.

Comment: From what I can see in the error, you seem to be indexing the `record` object using the string `'body'`. You could try to print out the `record` object along with its type with `type(record)` in order to get more information about this TypeError. As far as I can tell, `record` seems to be a string.